# Azure Blob Storage: Bulk populating the storage

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-storage

I have a snapshot of an image database from Access Web Online (AWO is being decommissioned in April 2018). The datasheet contains a lot of random variables and an URL to the image stored on a SharePoint server. I need to get the images stored at the URL's location stored in the Azure Blob Storage. Is it possible? If so, how would I do it? I have administrator access to all services.

I can mention that my experience on the field is lacking.

Comment: Are these image URLs publicly accessible? That is, if I take a URL and paste it in browser's address bar, will these images show?

Comment: They are publicly accessible.

Comment: The accepted answer, while being correct is an overkill IMHO. You don’t really need to download the files and upload them again considering the files are publicly accessible. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593136/how-can-upload-files-to-azure-blob-storage-from-web-site-images/43593502?noredirect=1#comment84950880_43593502. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion I would look at some way to automate this by scripting.

If scripting, I would split this problem into two parts.

1. Get the files from SharePoint
2. Upload the files to a blob storage

## Downloading from SharePoint

When looking at getting files from SharePoint, you have a couple of alternatives, again:

1. Use some external tool, and automate the download process, e.g. ShareGate
2. Write some script yourself

If scripting it all yourself, I would opt for using [SharePoint PnP PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell) cmdlets.

To download a file, simply run

```
$siteurl = "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com"  

#First connect to SPO
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl  

#Get the file
Get-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl /SPDocuments/Folder4/Files.docx -Path D:\Downloads -FileName SharePointFile.docx
```

Automate the retrieval process using the data you got at hand, the database. Export the paths as a .csv file and iterate over it in the script.

In this example I assume you are on SharePoint Online, but these cmdlets work for

- SharePoint 2013
- SharePoint 2016
- SharePoint Online

## Uploading the files to an Azure Storage Account

This part should be easier.

Here you can go the scripting route again and use:

1. [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps), i.e. `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` for uploading
2. [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/)
3. [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) to upload files from the command line

or you can use the graphical tool, [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to do it using a GUI.

**Note**: there are other ways to connect to a Storage Account also. I just listed the easiest ones for this specific case. However, you can also access a storage account programmatically, from e.g. C# code or using FTP.

[image: Azure Storage Explorer]

Using Azure Storage Explorer you can simply select the files you downloaded earlier and "copy & paste" them to your Azure Storage Account.

Comment: Nicely written - I have already accepted, although Connect-SPOnline should be Connect-PnPOnline - should it not? And Get-SPOFile is not in the list of cmdlets either - so I'm guessing Get-PnPFile is the correct one?

Comment: You are right, thanks for noticing that! Erwin wrote a blog post about why they did that change some time ago, https://www.erwinmcm.com/the-case-of-get-sposite/.